# Remove dashed line on drawing polyline

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the `Leaflet.Editable` plugin for the Leaflet library to let users draw lines on maps. How can I hide the temporary dash-line when drawing a new polyline?

Comment: Can you show what you mean in an example ? (use http://plnkr.co/ which is very handy for that)

Comment: Here you go:
http://plnkr.co/edit/192Y8nWjCeeHAVdsqjvi

When you start drawing (just click anywhere on the map), notice the blue dashed line as preview of the polyline. I was wondering whether this can be disabled somehow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize your map, you can pass it [editOptions](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable#options-1). The one that controls the dashed line is `lineGuideOptions`, which can be used to style the guide using any of Leaflet's [path options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-options). To hide the guide, you can simply set its `opacity` to 0. So if you initialize your map like this:

```js
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {
  editable: true,
  editOptions: {
    lineGuideOptions: {
      opacity: 0
    }
  }
}).setView(startPoint, 17);
```

you will be able to draw without any line guide. Updated plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/z7poIK3ul3kfGuEpQ3Us?p=preview